# Face recognition in Android without opencv

Tags: android, face-recognition

I wanted to develop a face recognition app in android. While searching, all i come up with is, the Opencv method, which i think is using C or C++. Can someone post the code or method for android? I am a newbie, so trying new stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV indeed uses C and C++ (and also Python), however you can try and use a java wrapper for the opencv library. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) is a nice wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer phone/tablet, you can use the face recognition API in Android 14+. Check out [Camera.Face](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html) and [Camera.FaceDetectionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.FaceDetectionListener.html)

Also make sure you call: [getMaxNumDetectedFaces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxNumDetectedFaces%28%29) to make sure you device supports the API.